# Does the nfc ring work with this rfid reader?

Tags: rfid, nfc

Is the [NFC ring](http://store.nfcring.com) compatible with [RFID Reader ID-20LA (125 kHz)](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11828) ? In [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159784/are-rfid-nfc-tags-and-readers-compatible-or-manufacturer-dependent) it is saying there are standards, but I cant find out weather the 2 products support any of those standards.

edit: in the faq of the ring i found out it supports ISO14443.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the NFC Ring FAQ page, http://store.nfcring.com/pages/faqs, they use the NXP NTAG203 chip as NFC tag in the ring. According to NXP the NTAG203 operates in the 13.56 MHz frequency band, http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/smart_label_and_tag_ics/ntag/series/NTAG203.html.

The RFID reader you have linked to operates in the 125 kHz frequency band, https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11828.

This means that the ring and reader is not compatible with each other. You need a reader that operates in the 13.56 MHz frequency band to be able to read the tag in the ring.